# Coordinates to MKPointAnnotation from CloudKit

Tags: ios, mapkit, cloudkit, cllocation, mkpointannotation

I have coordinates in CloudKit as Location data type ("Koordinaatit"). I'am trying to draw MKPointAnnotation to map from these coordinates but i don't know how to get coordinates from array to annotation.

```
var sijainnitArray:[CKRecord] = []


    func drawPin(sijainti: Int) {

         let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
         annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(sijainnitArray[sijainti].Koordinaatit) //XCode shows error: Value of type 'CKRecord' has no memeber 'Koordinaatit'
         self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}


func fetchRecordsFromCloud() {

        let cloudContainer = CKContainer.default()
        let publicDatabase = cloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Sijainti", predicate: predicate)

        publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {
            (results, error) -> Void in

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            if let results = results {
                print("Completed the download of locations data")
                self.sijainnitArray = results
                }
        })

    }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchRecordsFromCloud()

    let sijainnitLkm = sijainnitArray.count - 1

    for i in 0...sijainnitLkm {
        drawPin(sijainti: i)
        }
}



 **ANSWER**

let sijaintilista = self.sijainnitArray[i]

            let sijaintiLatLong = sijaintilista.object(forKey: "Koordinaatit") as? CLLocation
            let sijaintiLat = sijaintiLatLong?.coordinate.latitude
            let sijaintiLon = sijaintiLatLong?.coordinate.longitude

            let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: sijaintiLat!,  longitude: sijaintiLon!)
            let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)

            if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
                annotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
            }

            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use the method `object(forKey:)` on your `CKRecord`. Presumably the key you want to use is "Koordinaatit".

I haven't used CloudKit before. It looks like you can save a CLLocation directly into a `CKRecord`.

Comment: In locationManager location is saved to CloudKit CKRecord as CLLocation, problem is i don't know how to add CLLocation to MKPointAnnotation.

let location = locations.last!
        
        let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: "Sijainti")
        
        record.setObject(location, forKey: "Koordinaatit")
        
        publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: {
            (record, error) -> Void in

Comment: Ok, so you ned to read the record from cloudKit using `object(forKey:)` and then cast it to a `CLLocation`

Comment: Added solution to my answer. Thanks.